# how to filter issues that have PR associated on GitHub?

Tags: github, github-issues

I like to read issues that have PR in order to learn how a problem could be solved.

how can I filter issues that have PRs associated with them on GitHub?

Just read the PR directly isn't a solution: you could have some PR which hasn't an issue reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for issues which are linked to a pull request by a closing reference by using the [`linked:pr` qualifier](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-for-linked-issues-and-pull-requests). The following search query is what you want:

```
is:issue linked:pr
```